# Password value missing after POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So here is some code:

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetSettings()
{
    var save = new SettingsSaver();
    var dto = save.GetSettings();
    var model = new SettingsModel
    {
        Password = dto.Password,
        Port = dto.Port,
        Username = dto.Username,
        Enabled = dto.Enabled,
        Id = dto.Id,
        IpAddress = dto.IpAddress,
    };

    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSettings(SettingsModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var dto = new SettingsDto
        {
            IpAddress = viewModel.IpAddress,
            Password = viewModel.Password,
            Port = viewModel.Port,
            Username = viewModel.Username,
            Enabled = viewModel.Enabled,
            Id = viewModel.Id
        };

        var save = new SettingsSaver();
        var result = save.SaveSettings(dto); //Saves correctly and updates in DB
        if (result)
        {
            return View(); // Returns this
        }
        return View("Error");
    }
    return View("Error");
}
```

**View (Default Edit View)**

```
@model Dash.UI.Models.Settings.SettingsModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Settings";
}

<h2>Settings</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Settings</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Enabled, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Enabled)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Enabled, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IpAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IpAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IpAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Port, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Port, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Port, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

So, what the problem is when I update the model and `POST` to `GetSettings` it all works correctly, updates in the db etc. but on the `return View()` it does not hit the `GetSettings()` action method, but it returns the view with all of the model filled in except the password.

**Model**

```
public class SettingsModel : BaseSettingsViewModel // Base contains ID and Enabled properties with no data annotations
{
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("IP Address")]
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Port")]
    public int Port { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Any advise/guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon returning the same view from a POST, the ModelState will fill in the controls (apart from the password fields) from the posted values.

So you need a Post-Redirect-Get pattern:

```
if (result)
{
    return RedirectToAction("GetSettings");
}
```

Comment: Why apart from the password?

Comment: For security reasons, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, I should really be doing this anyway to stop people pressing F5 and resubmitting the form. I'll accept when I can.

Comment: Just one small remark. I hope you're not saving the passwords as clear text and you're encrypting them before you write it to the database? Really important for security reasons.

Comment: @Oceans what I am writing doesn't really require that. The passwords could be clear text on the screen and wouldn't really matter. They are not really 'passwords' in that sense.